# Am I responsible for Disposing a BackgroundImage?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose, idisposable

I have a windows form where I set the BackgroundImage property to a custom bitmap image.

```
private Image MakeCustomBackground()
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(100, 100);

    using(Graphics canvas = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        // draw the custom image
    }

    return result;
}

private void UpdateFromBackground()
{
    this.BackgroundImage = MakeCustomBackground();
}
```

My question is, Image is disposable and I am creating it, does that mean that I must dispose of it?  Or when I pass the image to the form, via BackgroundImage, does it take ownership and dispose of it when it no longer needs it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `UpdateFromBackground()` is called more than once, you probably should Dispose the *old* Image when (before) setting a new one. If you don't then the GC will do it eventually but that is less efficient. The Form will only Dispose the last BgImage you assigned.

```
private void UpdateFromBackground()
{
    if (this.BackgroundImage != null)
    {
       this.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
    }
    this.BackgroundImage = MakeCustomBackground();
}
```

Comment: Once you overwrite the BackgroundImage property, assuming there are no other references to the Image instance, GC will eventually take care of it as Henk stated. I'd just like to stress that the instance is not explicitly disposed by the Control so it's best practice to dispose of it yourself. You can test this by using two different variables, imageA and imageB, each set to a distinct Image instance. Set BackgroundImage to imageA and then to imageB, then test to see if imageA has been disposed—you'll see that it hasn't been.